# Can I modify the template used for Firebase's email link-based authentication?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm walking through the steps described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth#send_an_authentication_link_to_the_users_email_address) and upon sending the verification email to myself, I get an email in my inbox from `noreply@myappname.firebaseapp.com`.

For other email-based auth steps, I can customize the sender name and email address directly from the Firebase console:

[image]

Am I missing something that could help me with Email Link sign-in or do I need to go through the process of modifying the SMTP settings in my app's console?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the same behavior / restriction in the Firebase console. Considering that the underlying `.firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword` method could write your new user to firestore, i guess you could use firebase function to trigger a custom email via sendGrid, for example, and you could flesh out a custom workflow from there.

This article, [Email via Firebase Firestore Cloud Function Triggers](https://hightechtele.com/articles/firestore-trigger-email) includes the code to trigger custom emails and could be adapted to your needs. I imagine the trick will be to get the `.emailValidated` property set to true. It may be as easy as switching the boolean - i don't know.

All in all, it seems like a lot of work just to get a customized validation email though. I would recommend you just stick with what they provide.